# ios sound no longer working in app (only on device)

Tags: audio, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I'm building an app that uses `AVAudioPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayerController`. The sound works perfectly on the simulator. I know sound works on my phone because other apps play sound just fine (like this one used to). When I start the video, I hear about 0.2s of the background music that's supposed to be playing. I'm getting no errors.

I don't even know where to start on this one. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the "occasional" blip of sound in my app, so I assumed my volume was fine. It turns out that my phone was switched to vibrate aka silent. I flipped the switch back and viola.

The new question is: Do I feel like a *moron*? Yes I do.

** EDIT **

I stumbled upon the idea to check the switch when I read an article on [Understanding the Side Switch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4085)